# Prove that the sequence $\frac{4n^2-3n}{2n^2−1}$ converges to the limit $2$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I know this has probably been asked 100 times, but I couldn't find anything resembling this and I've been on this easy number for 2 hours... My work is below.

We want to show that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n > N$, then $|x_n-2|<\epsilon$.
$$
|\frac{4n^2-3n}{2n^2−1}-2|=|\frac{4n^2-3n-4n^2+2}{2n^2−1}|\\
=|\frac{2-3n}{2n^2−1}|\\
<|\frac{2}{2n^2−1}|.
$$
So we want:
$$
\frac{2}{2n^2−1}<\epsilon\\
\frac{2}{\epsilon}<2n^2−1\\
\\\sqrt{\frac{\frac{2}{\epsilon}+1}{2}}<n.
$$

But taking n larger than that value does not work? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I must be making some kind of algebra error or going wrong in my reasoning, but I feel bad because this is literally the first number on the exercice sheet.

Comment: $|\frac{2-3n}{2n^2−1}|<|\frac{2}{2n^2−1}|$ is wrong.

Comment: In rational functions, if the polynomials have the same degree, then the limit of the function as $x \to \infty$ and $x \to -\infty$ is the ratio of the leading coefficients.  I'm not sure exactly what the name of that theorem is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\frac{2-3n}{2n^2−1}|=\frac {3n-2} {2n^{2}-1}\le \frac  {3n} {n^{2}}=\frac  3n<\epsilon$ if $n >\frac  3 {\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we can consider that $n\geq 2$.

Consequently, one has that

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{4n^{2} - 3n}{2n^{2} - 1} - 2\right| & = \left|\frac{3n - 2}{2n^{2} - 1}\right| \leq \frac{3n + 2}{n^{2}} \leq \frac{3n + n}{n^{2}} = \frac{4}{n} < \frac{4}{n_{\varepsilon}} < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna be a complete departure from your method, but you could approach it like so:

Consider the following:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2-3n}{2n^2-1}$$

By the rules of limits, if the limit exists, this is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2}{2n^2-1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n}{2n^2-1}$. Since $2n^2-1\gt 3n$ for all natural numbers greater than $2$, and the derivative of $3n$ is constant with the derivative of $2n^2-1$ being monotonic over $[2,\infty)$, this second (sub) limit is equal to $0$.

That was the easy one. For the first limit, it is helpful to rewrite $\frac{4n^2}{2n^2-1}$ as $2+\frac{2}{2n^2-1}$; then, by the same rule of limits we initially applied, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2}{2n^2-1}$ becomes $\lim_{n\to\infty}2+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{2n^2-1}$.

By similar reasoning as in the case of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n}{2n^2-1}$, the limit of $\frac{2}{2n^2-1}$ is $0$. Furthermore, the limit of a constant is just itself, so in total we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2-3n}{2n^2-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{2n^2-1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n}{2n^2-1}=2+0-0=2$$

As I said, this is quite a departure from your method, but I found it easier. Of course, if you're *required* to do it in the way you've asked the question then this will be no help at all, so my pending apologies for that.